# Can I apply for Russian tourism visa without residence permit in China, as a foreigner?

Tags: visas, russia, residency

I live in China but don't have residence permit as my visa is X2. In order to apply for Russian tourism visa from a third country, you must live there for more than 90 days with valid visa. I have visa, but do NOT have the residence permit.

In this case, can I apply for a tourism visa for Russia in China, as a foreigner? The information seems mixed, as some report the residence permit is required while others say the visa page scan is sufficient...

Comment: The reason for the downvote?

Comment: Do you have residency anywhere? I think it will be difficult to get an invitation without residency somewhere. Like, where would they even mail your visa to you?

Comment: @AussieJoe I attend language school and live in university campus, so the residency is not a problem. But I don’t need the resistance permit which is obtainable only for those who study more than 180 days.

Comment: Which country you are citizen of?

Comment: @Zhigalin Japan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official site of the Foreign Affairs Ministry of the Russian Federation:
Documents:
Tourist visa:

> 7. Для граждан третьих стран (не граждане КНР): копия визы или документа, дающего право на непрерывное нахождение в стране пребывания на период более 90 дней.

Free translation:

> For non-citizens of China, a copy of visa **or** an another document
>   which enables you to stay for more than 90 consecutive days.

So, just a visa is ok.

Note, the Russian Embassy in China recommends to **not** apply for visa directly but to use the Russian Visa Center in Beijing: http://www.russiavisa-china.cn/English/Tourist.html